# Can i add JSP scripts in HTML

Tags: html, jsp

I have a method in my JSp .

can i make a button onclick which i can call that method..?

code:-

```
<input type="button" value="Previous" onclick="<%i=i-1; %">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="button" value="Accept" onclick="<% int temp=req.add(pr); %>">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="button" value="Next" onclick="<%i=i+1; %>">
```

By any mean...can i do this?

Comment: For what reason do you want to call that method? Could you elaborate? If you do then maybe people here can suggest some alternate ways which will work.

Answer (score 0):

JSP is a server side technology. The onclick attribute runs a client side script.

In order to do anything with JSP, you need to issue a new HTTP request to the server.

In the following example, you would have your JSP check the value of `action` in the submitted form data and act according to that.

```
<form action="some.jsp" method="post">
 <div>
  <input type="submit" name="action" value="Previous">
  <input type="submit" name="action" value="Accept">
  <input type="submit" name="action" value="Next">
 </div>
</form>
```

You could also make an Ajax request to communicate with the server without leaving the current page, but you should [build on things that work](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/).

Answer (score 0):

you can't do it. Because JSP is the apprivitation for Java **Server** Pages. Javascript will be invoked from the Browser, while JSP will be executed from a servletcontainer.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I add JSP scripts in HTML?

Yes you can.

You can write sciptlet using `<% .. %>`.

What you are doing is ***not possible***.

---

What is possible is passing jsp variable value to javascript function or use jsp variable value as value of html tag.

Example:

```
<input type="text" value="<%= jspVariable %>" />
<input type="button" onClick="jsFunc('<%= jspVariable %>','1')" />
```